# Validate domain user/password in Installshield setup

Tags: authentication, installshield

I have domain,username,password as inputs. Any idea on how i can validate that the username exists and the password is valid via custom action in a Installshield setup. I am using a Basic MSI setup. I could not find any resources in the web regarding this.

Comment: What do you plan on writing this Custom Action in?  InstallScript, C/C++, VBScript, C#/VB.NET?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with custom actions installshield includes in `ISNetAPI.dll`.
You're a better man than me if you can find any documentation on this.

Add it to your binary table from `<ISProductFolder>\redist\language independent\i386\ISNetAPI.dll`

I collect the domain, username and password and set properties to names that make sense to me. Then  when the 'next' button is clicked, it sets the properties the action expects.  If the username or domain is empty, it spawns a dialog telling the user.  If all is well, we go to the next dialog.

[image: Behavior of dialog]

Comment: Have you found these IS provided custom actions to be slow?  I created a sample project and all of the validation takes 10+ seconds per click for me.

Answer (score 0):

Could write an Installscript or C++ CA and call the API function **LogOnUser**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx